# How to transfer the value of the inner html of a div to a hidden input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to make the dynamic value of a div into a value that is put on a hidden input?

Id like for the innerhtml value of this:

```
<div class="totals-value" id="total"></div>
```

to be inserted here

```
<input type="hidden" name="grandtotal" value="">
```

Comment: Yes, this is very possible but what have you tried so far and cant you give an example of what that *"innerhtml value"* will be?

Comment: Looks like your div has no innerHTML

Comment: @CommercialSuicide it has one but is dynamically made so I don't know how I can capture the value. I'll try the answer CarlMarkham gave.

Comment: If you're going to use JavaScript and AJAX, you might as well just use a `var` instead. Comment only.

Comment: if you search 1> how to get the inner html 2> how to put a string as a value of a input field. and then combine you can answer your own question.

Comment: @PHPglue Sadly I'm not really familiar with Ajax.

Comment: You definitely need to know AJAX. Put that on your list of things to learn.

Comment: @Xkajl The answer isn't mine, I just edited it :)

Comment: @Xkajl AJAX is very useful when posting data if you want to keep the client on the same page and wait for a response from the request. If you post data to the same page you are reloading the whole page again where as with ajax you can append new things to the page or replace things on the page without the need of reloading. Just a quick understanding of the benefits of using AJAX.

Comment: @NewToJS I'll learn it I guess. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Xkajl You are very welcome, we all have to start somewhere and learning is the key to moving forward. Being told about things you weren't aware of can help make learning much easier and have a better outcome but sometimes you have to ask to find out :) Wish you the best of luck with your project and learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let $input = $('input[name="grandtotal"]');
let $div = $('#total');

$input.val( $div.html() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the value of hidden input. My snippet with two buttons "Insert value from div to input" and "Show hidden input" will give you an option to play around with it:

```js
const input = $('input[name="grandtotal"]');
const div = $('#total');

function insert() {
  input.val(div.html());
}

function showInput() {
  input.prop('type', 'text');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="totals-value" id="total">123</div> 
to be inserted here

<input type="hidden" name="grandtotal" value="">

<button onclick="insert()">Insert value from div to input</button>
<button onclick="showInput()">Show hidden input</button>
```

Comment: will it still work if the div originally has no innerhtml value written and is made real time?

Comment: Depends on how you framework works, but I think yes, it should work with dynamically updated elements

Comment: @CommercialSuicide your answer is longer but it's also good ++

Comment: @Nice to hear it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var theHiddenInput = $('input[name=grandtotal]');
var theDiv = $("#total");

theHiddenInput.val(theDiv.text());
```

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: the same question

Comment: the same answer

Comment: the same answer

Comment: Please don't just add an answer without looking at the others. This is exactly the same (different variable names) as an answer that has already been given.

Comment: no there is one more difference with `text()`. ok, my mistake, @CarlMarkham

Comment: OP asked for `innerHtml` not text

Comment: I think that my answer is differ. Isn't it? It's more complex and give to OP the option to test the behavior. Is it bad?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide I wasn't commenting on your answer

Comment: Sorry, my fault